# Why is √n the optimal value for m in a jump search?

Tags: algorithm, search

I am currently learning about searching algorithms and I came across jump search, which has a time complexity of O(√n). Why is √n the optimal value for m (jump size) in the jump search algorithm and how does it affect the time complexity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let *m* be the jump size and *n* be the number of elements.

In the worst case, the maximum number of elements you have to check is the maximum number of jumps (n/m - 1) plus the number of elements between jumps (m), and the time you take is approximately proportional to the total number of elements you check.

The goal in choosing *m*, therefore, is to minimize: (n/m)+m-1.

The derivative by *m* is 1 - (n/m<sup>2</sup>), and the minimum occurs where the derivative is 0:

1 - (n/m<sup>2</sup>) = 0

(n/m<sup>2</sup>) = 1

n = m<sup>2</sup>

m = √n

Comment: How did you find the derivative of m?

Comment: n/m + m -1 is nm^-1 + m - 1.  You can use power rule for all the terms: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/power-rule.html  And of course you can just add the derivatives for the terms following the sum rule: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the block size is k, the worst case scenario requires roughly n / k iterations for finding the block and k iterations for finding the element in the block.

To minimize n / k + k where n is a constant, we can use differentiation (see Matt's answer) or the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)  to get:

n / k + k >= 2sqrt(n)

We can clearly see that 2sqrt(n) is the minimal number of iterations and is attainable when k = sqrt(n).